# PhpStorm crashes on startup

Tags: phpstorm

I installed PhpStorm on my machine (Windows XP) at work. At first it was fine and I used it for a day or so. After the installation of (likely) an incompatible plugin, the IDE freezes on startup.

I already tried reinstalling and updating Java. I even cleared the registry of any JetBrains and PhpStorm entries and installed it again.

I've searched the JetBrains forums, but it seems the problem I have is not a common one.
Maybe one of you had the same issue?

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to delete application plug-ins/caches. If it doesn't help, also delete settings. [See the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) for the directories locations on your system.

Most likely **idea.log** contains the exceptions from the plug-in which causes this problem. I'd recommend sending this log to the plug-in vendor.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but the plugin is not installed anymore. Still, it doesn't work. Also I have no user-specific settings stored in my home-directory

Comment: Look carefully, you should have .WebIdeXX directory in your home. Removing it should help. If it doesn't help and you are sure that there is no such directory, provide a thread dump: http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-260.

Comment: found the settings-folder....was hidden in a network-drive. the company stores the user-files on a server -_-'

Comment: Note that you may want to move it to your local disk per FAQ, otherwise you may have performance issues.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have been using webstorm and noticed that if for some reason my computer crashes (power outage etc) all the files open at webstorm get replaced by same filenames but empty files! Have you had that experience?

Comment: @Cgraphics that can be specific to OS/file system/hardware caches.

Comment: @CrazyCoder nope! We did not notice such a thing with eclipse. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961240/webstorm-crashes-and-all-my-settings-gone

Comment: @Cgraphics there is nothing you can do about it except backups.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Sure but see this is a professional product for which we are paying. It can easily be fixed ( close files at any updates). I think you work for jetbrain; Do you think addressing this bug is in TODO list?

Comment: @Cgraphics it's offtopic here. Open a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and describe the problem there.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and followed @CrazyCoder's instructions (thank you!), but the  error turned out to be with related to indexing.

I reopened the IDE, and hurried to `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart ...`

Answer (score 1):

Had a different issue (Ubuntu 20.x)

**My use case :**

I launched phpstorm and hit "cancel" while it was automatically reloading my last project (which closed PS immediately)

Then, trying to launch it just did show the splash screen for some seconds... and nothing. (tried it several times).

It turned out the process were still somewhere, while no GUI was visible.

`ps aux | grep phpstorm` had several (many) results.

*All those zombie processes moaning "JetBraiiiiiiins" was a quite terrifying sight to me*

Solution ?  Kill'em all !

**`pkill -f phpstorm`**

Answer (score 0):

I met similar issue while starting my PhpStorm 7.
Then I followed CrazyCoder's instructions to delete a new-installed plug-in at `~/Library/Application Support/WebIde70` (using Mac) and it finally works...

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\username.PhpStorm2016.1\system\LocalHistory

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, when running `pstorm` from the terminal, it may complain about:

```
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/user/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PhpStorm/ch-0/201.7846.90/jbr/lib/libjfxmedia.so)
```

Which can be fixed by adding this into `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib64
```