# Webstorm crashes and all my settings gone

Tags: javascript, ide, webstorm

I was working with my webstorm 7.0.3 which used for editing the javascript code. All of the sudden something went wrong with my system and everything froze! Had to cold reboot the system and when restarted the webstorm i saw these error messages stating that none of my settings that I spent hours to create ( and of course saved) can be restored!

This is has may be a serious bug in websotrm which may cause lack of reliability of this product

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 3]

[image: screenshot 3]

Comment: So .. you have **File System corruption on OS level** and you blame this product for not able to read/load **already corrupted** data? Delete all what you have at `C:\Users\USERNAME\.WebStorm7` and start from scratch (but check your disk/file system for errors first).

Comment: @LazyOne well how come Eclipse does not create such issue in similar scenario? Needless to mention that if WebStorme closes file each time updates them, no such a problem would have happened! Webstorm is the one corrupting the files

Comment: I've been using PhpStorm (almost the same as WebStorm; since 0.x version) -- not a single crash (because of IDE) or corruption (any kind), even when PC was halt and hard reboot was required -- using Windows 7 ATM. IDE does not keep files open after writing to them -- I can safely delete any file from the project and IDE will only notify me of that fact -- will not crash. But yes -- I have not tried deleting IDE config files (corruption subject in your case). So **from my point/experience** it's hard to blame IDE for this.

Comment: I do remember seeing a forum thread (or maybe it was a ticket -- was over a year ago, I think) where user stated that few files that were opened in editor (out of few more) were empty (on both disk and IDE) after computer was booted after power failure (hard reboot, basically). Files were recovered from Local History (which cover project files only and not config folder). Yes, index/cache corruption happens from time to time even on normal shut down (no idea why) .. but this one is a first time when I hear about such behaviour regarding config files. Dunno what else to add.

Comment: If you are having such problems with your computer often (when you need to do hard reboot) and you cannot replace your hardware / solve the issue with such behaviour, then **for the future** (when you will have it all configured and decide to stick with this IDE, of course) I may only advise to setup some sort of **continuous backup** of IDE config folder (it should include only `config` folder and exclude `system` which contains indexes/caches and other frequently updated support files).

Answer (score 6):

There is a hidden folder **.idea** inside the webstorm working directory. Remove that folder and try again.

Answer (score 0):

maybe late, but this just happened to me on `PhpStorm2018.3` upgrade.

one can just reclaim ownership on files inside `.idea` directory and change the read-only attribute on all files inside `.idea`.

for linux:

`sudo chown -R user:group .idea` inside a project dir (root dir where `.idea` resides)

and then

`chmod +r -R .idea` also inside a root dir of the project